# Can I insert PHP and javascript code in the same HTML file?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<HTML>
    <script language="JavaScript">  
        <script language="php">
        </script>
    </script>
</HTML>

<HTML>
    <script language="php">
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript">  
    </script>
</HTML>
```

I want to insert PHP and javascript code in HTML code like above.
Can I do this work??

Comment: you cant do this in php
as it really does not make any sense to add some php script in html like this
please clarify your question

Comment: Sure you can. Just replace those javascript type of tags with `<?php`. As long as the server or the browser (depending upon what language it is) can process, you can put whatever you want (know as spaghetti code), but you shouldn't.

Comment: [PHP <script language=“php”> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10769065/388053) might helps.

Comment: You can generally make the second HTML block work if you configure your webserver to understand the php script tag as PHP code. But what you cannot do is insert any tags inside a <script> tag according to the HTML definition.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't work like that, you can have them in the same file per se, just not like you have.

PHP is executed on the server and the result is sent to the client, whereas the JS code is executed by the client's browser.

```
<?php
//php code in here is evaluated and the result sent to the client
$somevar = 1234;
?>
<HTML>
     <script language="JavaScript">  
        //javascript in here is evaluated by the client
        //you could insert PHP values here to be used in JS if you want
        //make sure you escape them though...
        var some_js_var = <?php echo $somevar; ?>
        //the JS var above would contain the value of php variable $somevar
    </script>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I guess it's good to mention that the above should actually be a .php file (unless .html is configured to be treated in the same way as .php).

Comment: The main question here is, **can php, javascript, html put in the same file?** answer is, yes you can.

Answer (score 2):

```
<HTML>
<script language="JavaScript">  
    <?php 
      // Your PHP code here that outputs javascript
      ?>
</script>
</HTML>

<HTML>
    <?php 
      // Your PHP code here that outputs text/html code
      ?>
<script language="JavaScript">  
</script>
</HTML>
```

But of course, as others pointed out, browser will not see your PHP code. It will be processed by the server and browser will see only the javascript/html.

Answer (score 1):

sure, you can even make php generate javascript. php file is processed to html before sending it to client, and client will see nothing except html with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can also insert your code like this, don't give error

```
<HTML>
    <script language="JavaScript">  
        <script language="php">
           echo "alert('javascript alert')";
        </script>
    </script>
</HTML>

<HTML>
    <script language="php">
         echo "php code runned";
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript">  
    </script>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want php to be executed inside javascript, then you have to use AJAX.

AJAX is a javascript code that allows you to call the server, thus executing php code and returning the result to you, at any time you wish (not only at the creation time of the page, but at the time the javascript code is called).

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

with jquery is even easier:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

**You can put PHP code in the middle of a fichero.js???**

Many do not know, but not in principle. If the server to interpret a php file needs to see the php extension, note that you can not set or if the file is php html extension, therefore you're not a js file extension. What you can do is something like the php type="javaScript">   '; echo 'write ("'. $ name. '");'; echo ''; } ?> For example.